# getting parent option jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, syntax

I'm using jquery ui to position each image div inside their parent div. Like this:

```
<div class="section">
     <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the parent with jquery. These are the options I'm using:

```
$(".image").each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), $target = $this.parent();
    $this.position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: $target
    });
});
```

Is there a syntax issue with using jquery as an option? Any help would be great.

Comment: Parent? Only: `$this.parent()` without `next()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just .parent().

`.next()` selects the sibiling of the container. However, I suggest to use `.closest(".section")` instead.

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is not dependent on the presence of another wrapper between your image and the .section div: you will select the first container with a "section" class.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for you

```
 $(".image").each(function() {

    $(this).position({
      my: "center",
      at: "center",
      of: $(this).parent()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want get parent div that inside it is your image i have to say you can simply say
"1" and if you want an image tag selecting by its parent  you can use theses codes "2".

```
1- $(".section")
2- $(".section>.image") or $(".section .image")
```